# Tool Tip Issue Popup not showing on the top layer of a form

Tags: javascript, popup

I have created a number of tool tips in JavaScript for use in a form.

My problem is that the tool tips always popup under the field that I am trying to create the help for and are unreadable.

Is there anyway I can make the Tooltip always display on the top of the form?

Any help would be greatly apprecoiated.

Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: Take a look at z-index https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index, beyond that you will need to provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can most likely be fixed by adding a z-index to the element that the popup is contained in that is higher than that of the form.

Try adding the following css to your popup:

```
z-index:1000;
```

This will put everything with a z-index of 999 and lower below the popup. You can view more info about the z-index property here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp and if you need more help please post a bit of your code so we can better assist you.

Comment: Tx will try tonight. Best regards Mike